# What field property may allow faster than $c$ speed?

Tags: general-relativity, waves, faster-than-light, gravitational-waves

1. What field property may allow faster than $c$ speed?
2. Is there theoretical field or what property it needs to have to allow wave speed larger than $c$?
3. What is the speed of the gravitational wave?
4. Is the gravity speed set artificially equal to $c$ in the Maxwell equations for gravity?

Comment: There is no physical system that can propagate causal effects that are faster than the speed of light. One can cause correlations that seem to be propagating faster than c, though.

Comment: While faster than $c$ speed may be allowed in GR, you'll find that accelerating a sub-$c$ speed to above $c$ (which is the useful part of all this) is impossible

Answer (score 1):

Phase velocity can be more than speed of light as written here in  [Phase Velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity)

but it is not the real speed of energy or information.

Another interesting article is [Cherenkov Radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation).

Answer (score 0):

**For matter-wave**:
P=h/,
 P=mv,
w=f 
E=mc<sup>2</sup>and,
E=hf leads to
 **v.w=c<sup>2</sup>** by equating E(energy) and P(momentum)
 where v=particle velocity and w=wave velocity
 since particle velocity is always less than speed of light it seems wave velocity of matter-wave theoritically exceeds speed of light...

Answer (score 0):

Gravitational waves are believed to travel with the speed of light.

Within the framework of General Relativity Miguel Alcubierre has proposed a metric (*Alcubierre metric*) which allows for an apparent faster-than-light travel. It is purely theoretical and to generate such a metric one would need negative energy densities.